# How to unit test that a Flask app's routes are protected by authlib's ResourceProtector?

Tags: python, flask

I've got a Flask app with some routes protected by [authlib's ResourceProtector](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/2/resource-server.html).

I want to test that a route I've set up is indeed protected by a `authlib.integrations.flask_oauth2.ResourceProtector` but I don't want to go to the trouble of creating a valid jwt token or anything like that. I want to avoid feeling like I'm testing `authlib`, rather than testing my code.

All I really need to do is check that when I hit my endpoint, the `ResourceProtector` is called. This should be possible with mocking of some kind, but I wonder if there's a supported way to do this.

```py
from authlib.integrations.flask_oauth2 import ResourceProtector

require_auth = ResourceProtector()
require_auth.register_token_validator(validator)

APP = Flask(__name__)


@APP.route("/")
@require_auth(None)
def home():
    return "Authorized!"
```

The test should look something like this:

```py
from my_module import APP

class TestApi:

    @property
    def client(self):
        return APP.test_client()

    def test_response_without_oauth(self):
        response = self.client.get("/")

        assert response.status_code == 401

    def test_response_with_auth0(self):
        # Do some mocking or some magic
        response = self.client.get("/")

        assert response.text == "Authorized!"
```

Comment: Hi @letu, yes I'm familiar with `unittest.mock`. The question is how and what to mock in order to be able to assert that the `ResourceProtector` is indeed called when I access the `"\"` route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flask docs subtly refer to [Application Factories](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/appfactories/) as having a use case involving testing:

> So why would you want to do this?
>
> 1. Testing. You can have instances of the application with different settings to test every case.
>
> ...

We can use an application factory to keep code out of the top-level which makes life hard for mocking (because by the time you've imported the module, the thing you're hoping to mock has already been defined.)

```py
from authlib.integrations.flask_oauth2 import ResourceProtector


def create_app():
    """The name `create_app` is magic: you can't rename it"""

    require_auth = ResourceProtector()
    require_auth.register_token_validator(validator)

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    @require_auth(None)
    def home():
        return "Authorized!"
```

This means we can then test the route as normal like this:

```py
from my_module import create_app
from authlib.integrations.flask_oauth2 import ResourceProtector


class TestApi:

    def test_endpoint_is_protected(self):
        
        client = create_app().test_client()

        with patch("my_module.ResourceProtector", wraps=ResourceProtector) as mock:
            client().get(self.ENDPOINT)
            mock.assert_called_once()
```

To then test the route without having to worry about auth at all, you could tweak the server a little bit to use [the `optional` argument](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/2/resource-server.html#optional-require-oauth):

```
def create_app(auth_is_optional = False):
    
    ...

    @app.route("/")
    @require_auth(None, optional=auth_is_optional)
    def home():
        return "Authorized!"
```

We can now ignore auth in testing by calling `create_app` with `auth_is_optional=True`.

This approach, of having keyword arguments to `create_app` for config, is recommended by [the docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/appfactories/#factory-improvements):

> Make it possible to pass in configuration values for unit tests so that you don’t have to create config files on the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to simply patch the call of the decorator.

ResourceProtector is imported on app startup. `security.api_protection`is the module path of this file.

```
from security.token_validator import AADTokenValidator
from authlib.integrations.flask_oauth2 import ResourceProtector

require_oauth = ResourceProtector()
validator = AADTokenValidator()
require_oauth.register_token_validator(validator)
```

Controller

```
@upload_api.route(/upload", methods=['POST'])
@require_oauth(['Upload'])
def upload_file():
```

The test simply ignores the call of the decorator:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('security.api_protection.require_oauth.acquire_token', lambda x: x).start()
class TestUploadController(unittest.TestCase):
```

Authorization is now ignored in the testcase.